# How to make a header stick at top when keyboard appears (iPhone) on input click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a chat app which consists of a header, content and sometimes footer (when not in a chat view).

I have already made my header and footer "sticky" such that they always appear in front of the content and stay at the top and bottom. However, when I press on an input box and start typing, the header is pushed away from the screen to the top. Ideally I would like the footer and content to be scrolled away but that the header stays - at the top and in front.

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #1A1A1A;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    padding-top: 65px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 2.5;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 1.8px;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #1A1A1A;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"> Header /div>

<div id="content"> Header 

 <input  class="chatinput" placeholder="Start typing..." ng-model="newPost"/>

/div>

<div id="footer"> Header /div>
/div>
```

**How to achieve this?

Is this related to overscroll?**

Comment: please add your code and not fake css as 'postition:fixed'

Comment: I have added it, but the position fixed and top were the most crucial parts

Comment: postition isn't a valid css attribute, please add your real code, better if you can provide a JSFiddle, or a SO code snippet

Comment: Can you provide an example using http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I read about the position attribute here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp Am on phone now so difficult to create JSFiddle, maybe later.

Comment: ok your question is too broad

Comment: I have updated the description and added the full example, also it should be more clear what I mean now.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why my question gets downvoted, it is not that weird what I am asking?? Basically, the answers provided and my REAL code submitted do not work. Clicking on the input box lets the header really disappear in safari (up)

Answer (score 0):

**You should provide an example the next time.**

This code will keep the header always on the top of your window.

```
#header {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you but that does not work when opening in safari. Yes the header remains at the top, but when I press on an input box at the bottom, the whole page gets shifted to the top, including the header.